# dataframe having list items and we're checking a value is present there or not in each row in that DF

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe :

```
df = structure(list(session_id = 1:14, rv = list(c(1, 2, 3), 4, c(5, 
6), c(7, 8), 5, c(9, 6, 10, 10), c(9, 6), c(11, 9, 12, 13), c(8, 
3, 9), 3, 14, c(13, 11, 15), c(6, 6), 16)), row.names = c(NA, 
14L), vars = list(session_id), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("session_id", 
"rv"), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now i want to check if value 9 is present in what rv columns grouped by session ids.
Eg. checking first row rv[[1]] 9 is not present return 0 .Again check for 2nd row rv[[2]] 9 is not present ....in 6th row rv[[6]] 9 is present so returns its index position 1 ...Likewise in 9th row of rv[[9]] 9 is present at 3rd index return it.......So the idea is if value 9 is present in rv return index position else return 0.

I hope this in enough to expalin what the idea is.

Looking for dplyr way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of `dplyr` and `purrr` you can try:

```
df %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(index = map_int(rv, function(l) if_else(any(l == 9), which.max(l == 9), 0L)))

# A tibble: 14 x 3
   session_id        rv index
        <int>    <list> <int>
 1          1 <dbl [3]>     0
 2          2 <dbl [1]>     0
 3          3 <dbl [2]>     0
 4          4 <dbl [2]>     0
 5          5 <dbl [1]>     0
 6          6 <dbl [4]>     1
 7          7 <dbl [2]>     1
 8          8 <dbl [4]>     2
 9          9 <dbl [3]>     3
10         10 <dbl [1]>     0
11         11 <dbl [1]>     0
12         12 <dbl [3]>     0
13         13 <dbl [2]>     0
14         14 <dbl [1]>     0
```

Here I use `map_int` because the input is a list and you want to have an integer as output. 
In case there are several 9 in one of the vectors, it returns the first index.

I had to use `ungroup` as your data.frame is a "rowwise_df".

Comment: yeah your answer is helpful but the rv list somehow sorted in ascending order and giving not actual indexes ..you look output .For 6 and 7 row 9 was 1 element

Comment: Yeah you're right! This happend, because I used `which.min`, instead of `which.max`. 
`which.max` finds the first index which is TRUE, `which.min` returns the first index which is FALSE.